# Where to locate common services in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I have just created my new project following :

```
https://angular.io/guide/styleguide
```

1 thing I don't understand however following that guide is where to locate common services (by instance, 1 getting all the invoices, or all the clients) that may get used in several different modules.

I was just thinking creating repositories like "`invoice/shared/invoice.service.ts`" (my `invoice` dir would only contain a `shared` dir as I don't have any module/component linked to it).

Is this a good practice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular recommends to put all the services and components that are used in more than one module in a shared module.

It is explained [on the ngModule page](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#shared-modules).

So, the final distribution could be:

```
/app
  /module_1
  /module_2
  /shared
     shared.module.ts
     /services
        invoice.service.ts
```